# Why is this footer not displaced by these floated elements?

Tags: html, css

What I want is to make my page a little responsive for desktop browsers.

For example, when I decrease the width of the browser, the left and right portion of the page should be stacked over each other. Please check the code, you'll understand. The outerLeft and outerRight div are floated left and right respectively. When I decrease the width of browser, outerRight goes below outerLeft, which is good. But then the problem is with **footer** and **copyright** (last two divs at bottom) divs. These do not get displaced because of the outerRight div. I want them to be below outerRight. How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<body style="margin: 0px">
<div class="outer">
    <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="outerLeft">
    <h1><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="login.php">WinkCage</a></h1>
    <br />
    <p>Instant Messaging web application</p>
  </div>
  <div class="outerRight">
    <div class="loginform">
      <form name="form2" method="post">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username" required/></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required/></td>
            <td><input id="logbutton" type="submit" name="sub" value="Login"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <p><?php echo $loginerror; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="signform">
      <form id="signupform" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required /></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div class="propic"><img id="imgid" src="images/dp.png" /></div>
              <input id="imgInput" type="file" name="image" required/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}" title="The username must contain minimum 6 and ONLY alphanumeric characters."/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="digits" type="text" name="phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your phone no." pattern=".{10}" required title="Invalid entry. Minimum 10 digits are required."/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="typechange" type="password" name="password" maxlength="12" placeholder="Enter password" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}" title="The password must contain at least 5 and ONLY alphanumeric characters."/>
              <div id="seepass"></div></td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <div id="userexist"></div>
      <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div style="font-family: calibri; text-align: center; color: black; font-size: 16px; padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; display: block;" href="login.php">WinkCage &copy; 2016</a></div>
<div style="height: 7px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px grey; background-color: white; display: block"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    }
#header{
    height: 20%;
    }
.outer{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 94%;
    display: block;
    }
.outerLeft{
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 145px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }
.outerRight{
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    }
.loginform{
    height: auto;
    width: 480px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 23px;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    }
.loginform input{
    width: 187px;
    height: 21px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }
#logbutton{
    background-color: #00CC66;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 70px;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.signform{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 480px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    }
.signform input{
    width: 250px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
#button{
    background-color: #0099FF;
    color: white;
    width: 188px !important;
    height: 41px !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px grey;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    }
.propic{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px grey;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: grey;
    }
#imgInput{
    width: 187px !important;
    height: 22px !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
#imgid{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a `clear: both` just this!

```
<div style="font-family: calibri;text-align: center;color: black;font-size: 16px;padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;clear: both;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; display: block;" href="login.php">WinkCage © 2016</a></div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uorm91pL/)**

*Note: I suggest you to do not use `inline-css`*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want..
Since you have an element with height 94% - I'd say you always want to see that footer (being fixed on the bottom..) and generate the scroll just for that outer element.

If that's what you want, you can just include an `overflow: auto` in the .outer class.

```
.outer {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 94%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Take a look here..
https://jsfiddle.net/uvqk4eeL/1/